# How Can we disable Camera and Microphone for xamarin webview?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webrtc

I deleted permissions camera and audio from manifest file, and added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />
```

but when I loading page https://browserleaks.com/webrtc or https://pixelscan.net I see, that wertc still working

Comment: You probably need to intercept the permission requests from the browser and not grant them. So you need to interact with the WebView class and use the settings and clients you can override in that to do so.

Comment: In general, when you delete the permissions in the list file, xamarin webView may not call the camera and microphone. If possible, you may show all your manifest files.